# Is there a way of using an anonymous class in a typedef?

Tags: c++

Consider

```
template<class Base> struct ChildT : Base
{
};
struct NoBase{};
typedef ChildT<NoBase> Child;
```

Is there a way of writing this `typedef` so you don't need to define `NoBase`? I'm thinking of something like the following:

```
typedef ChildT<class {}> Child;
```

Comment: BTW, `using` syntax is clearer than old `typedef` syntax (`using Child = ChildT<NoBase>;`)

Comment: Not possible. The grammar production simply doesn't allow it. The moment you pop a `{` there, it's ill-formed.

Comment: Even `using Child = ChildT<decltype([](){struct {} s; return s;})>;` is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate), which is defined just like your `NoBase`.

As you can see from the link it is not been thought for your use case, but essentially it can. After all, it's just a unit type.

I'm not sure whether `std::monostate` is the only empty `struct` in the STL. Nothing comes to mind, except `std::nullptr_t`, which however is not defined as `struct nullptr_t {}` but as `decltype(nullptr)`, so it is not an alternative to `std::monostate`.

Comment: That's nice - I need to convince my boss to move to C++17.

Comment: @P45Imminent O thanks, didn't know about monostate.

And yes moving to C++17 is a good move specially if you're still on '98.
Also ask for some refactoring time too while you're at it ;) (hoping you have unit tests).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this :

```
namespace details
{
    struct none
    {
    };
}

template<typename Base = details::none>
struct ChildT :
    public Base  // be sure to use the correct inheritance, private is default
{
    void do_something() {}
};

using Child = ChildT<>;

int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.do_something();
}
```

Note : after reading the other answers std::monostate does the same as details::none :)

Comment: "private is default" - take care there, that's not true for `struct`s although I wouldn't bet my job on whether the inheritor or inheritee dictates the default access.

Comment: @Bathsheba Oh yeah was thinking class here :). In any case I learned myself to be explicit